# SSO working functionality in different browser

Tags: single-sign-on

we are using SAML protocol.

I have some doubt on the SSO functionality in different browser.

If i enter my application url in chrome then it is asking for credential that is correct one and then we are on landing page.

Now i have enter same url on different browser i.e Mozilla then again it is asking for credential but that should not asked the credential once again.

Give me proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

SAML 2.0 is typically a browser-based flow. That means unless Chrome and Firefox are sharing cookies, which I know of absolutely no way to do, that's not going to work. SSO is *tied* to the browser.

The behavior you're describing as a problem isn't a problem, it's a feature.

N.B. There are some ways to tie a single sign-on session to, i.e. a Windows login, but AFAIK getting that to work with Chrome isn't going to be easy (if possible), as you'd need to use Kerberos/SPNEGO. There are also very limited use cases for this, such as in a corporate environment, where you want AD users already authenticated to say, a company intranet site.